# static content page in ionic takes time to load first time on mobile

Tags: html, angular, ionic2, ionic3, static-content

I have static page which contains more then 300 lines of text in the html page.

```
    <ion-content> 
      <p text-warp>
        //my text with
      </p> 
    </ion-content>
```

In my browser i am able to navigate to my static page immediately but after build to my mobile at first time it take lot of time to navigate to that page.

i have tested this with 3 mobiles same result.

i am using `ionic cordova build android`

What might cost the issue

output of `ionic info`

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.8
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.4.2
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.1
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.10
```

Comment: Which CLI command have you used?

Comment: @Sampath CLI ??? means

Comment: It means Angular CLI, like ng build --prod -aot, etc...

Comment: @Sampath i have updated my question

Comment: @Vega i have updated my question

Comment: So I guess no routing animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `--prod` option with your CLI command.It Marks as a `production` build.

> ionic cordova run android --prod

after using the above command the build will be optimized

Here is the [**ionic cordova run Options**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/)

> --prod triggers a production build of Ionic, which is then put into the Cordova container you chose (android or ios).

These tasks are available within `ionic-app-scripts`:

[**Reference:**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/README.md#all-available-tasks)

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between prod build and normal build and what does --prod does if you explain it will be very helpfull

Comment: There is no such CLI command like this now `ionic cordova build android`.You can see all the available list using above link.

Comment: in the same link at the very bottom check the second example it is `ionic cordova run ios` that is not using any `--prod` or `--device` and also it is also deploying and if there is not one can you give some explaination

Comment: in ionic https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md they have not mention anything about deprication of `ionic cordova run android` command

Comment: You need to find that on CLI Git repo: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/releases

Comment: What is the result  when you use this `ionic cordova run android --prod --device` ?

Comment: i am getting an error i have updated the answer please except it that works fine but --device throughs error

Comment: Yep, Done that.